# How can I add a string one at a time to a HashMap<Integer, List<String>>?

Tags: java, string, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

This function loops through a dictionary (allWords) and uses the 
getKey function to generate a key. wordListMap is a HashMap> so I need to loop through and put the key and and a List. If there is not a list I put one if there is I just need to append the next dictionary word. This is where I need help. I just can't figure out the syntax to simply append the next word to the list that is already there. Any Help would be appreciated.

```
public static void constructWordListMap() {
    wordListMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String w : allWords) {

        int key = getKey(w);

        if (isValidWord(w) && !wordListMap.containsKey(key)) {
            List list = new ArrayList();
            list.add(w);
            wordListMap.put(key, list);
        } else if (isValidWord(w) && wordListMap.containsKey(key)) {
            wordListMap.put(key, wordListMap.get(key).add(w));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map.get(key).add(value)
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

So I've gathered that you want to, given `HashMap<Integer, List<String>>`, you'd like to:

- create a `List` object
- add `String` objects to said `List`
- add that `List` object as a value to be paired with a previously generated key (type `Integer`)

To do so, you'd want to first generate the key

```
Integer myKey = getKey(w);
```

Then, you'd enter a loop and add to a `List object`

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>;
for(int i = 0; i < intendedListLength; i++) {
    String myEntry = //wherever you get your string from
    myList.add(myEntry);
}
```

Lastly, you'd add the `List` to the `HashMap`

```
myHash.put(myKey, myList);
```

Leave any questions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (isValidWord(w) && wordListMap.containsKey(key)) {
        wordListMap.put(key, wordListMap.get(key).add(w));
    }
```

If you want to add a new value to your list, you need to retrieve that list first. In the code above, you are putting the return value of add into the table (which is a boolean), and that is not what you want.

Instead, you will want to do as Paul said:

```
else if (isValidWord(w) && wordListMap.containsKey(key)) {
        wordListMap.get(key).add(w);
    }
```

The reason this works is because you already added an ArrayList to the table earlier. Here, you are getting that ArrayList, and adding a new value to it.